# Add unique_together validation check on internal attirbutes of JSONField

Tags: django, django-models

I am using following model.

```
class MyProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)
    account_id = models.CharField(max_length=64, default=None)
    prof_config = JSONField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    result = JSONField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)

    class Meta(object):
        app_label = "app"
        verbose_name = "MyProfile"
        unique_together = [["account_id", "prof_config"]]
```

Previously `prof_config` included:

```
prof_config =  {"username":"pranav","password":"123456"}
```

But now I have changed it to :

```
prof_config =  {"username":"pranav","password":"123456","last_sync_time":null}
```

And as I want `unique_together` validation only on account_id, username and password.
For that I changed `unique_together` to:

```
 unique_together = [["account_id", "prof_config__username","prof_config__password"]]
```

But it didn't work. It gave me following error (if last sync time is null for both profiles):

```
"Error while creating My Profile, error:duplicate key value violates unique 
constraint \"app_myprofile_account_id_prof_config_b94a5cdc_uniq\"\nDETAIL:  Key 
(account_id, prof_config)=(4, {\"password\": \"123456\", \"username\": \"pranav\", 
\"last_sync_time\": null}) already exists.\n", "causality": "", "opid": "fc3501fa", 
"opid_chain": "fc3501fa", "level": "ERROR"}
```

I am getting this error even after I have added  unique_together for account_id, username and password ([["account_id", "prof_config__username","prof_config__password"]]). But it's still taking whole `prof_config`. And If last sync time is different the profile is being created.

So Is there any way to do this.

Comment: why won't you use normal fields instead of JSONField? I'm not really sure unique_together works with JSONFields

Comment: The current requirement of our team as asked by out head is to put the fields entered by user into `prof_config` . So I have to use the JSONField.

Answer (score 2):

You can override `clean` method in ModelForm and do manual validation

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    # Your custom validation
    ...

    # raise error if something is not right
    raise ValidationError('Error')

    return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 0):

The error that you ran into is related to the existing data in your database,
The error is saying you have already data in the database that doesn't follow your new unique_together rule

You should find and remove/edit the specific record that caused this error